# MySQL query with join taking way too long

Tags: mysql, performance

I've got a simple enough query that's taking almost 4 minutes to run.

About the tables:

Table A has 25 columns and 18354 rows
Table B has 24 columns and 97889 rows

The query:

```
select (sum(a.a)/sum(a.ab)) as ab_avg,
sum(a.h) as h_sum,
((sum(a.2B) + sum(a.3B) + sum(a.4B))/sum(a.ab)) as b_avg,
(sum(a.sb) / (sum(a.sb) + sum(a.cs))) as sb_pct,
(sum(a.ab) / (sum(a.hr)) as ab_hr_ratio,
(sum(a.ab) / sum(a.so)) as ab_so_ratio,
b.lastname,
b.firstname
from a, b
where b.id = a.id
group by b.year
```

MySQL returns exactly what it should, but I'd imagine this query should not take 4 minutes to run.  Is there something I did wrong that's causing the performance issue?

Comment: You imagined it to take 4 minutes, so what's the problem?

Comment: Try to add indexes on year field and id fields

Comment: You have indexes on the ids and years, I hope?

Comment: Why are you aggregating by `b.year` and not including it in the `select`?  Why do you have `firstname` and `lastname` in the `select`, but you are not aggregating by them?  And, can you edit the query to include table aliases to make it clear which columns are coming from which tables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added indexes to year and id and it runs in .45 seconds.  Thanks!